# Access UI gets hung up

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have an access database that I'm working with. In said database I have built a form that runs a search engine. This search engine ranks the results based on relevancy. Depending on the search there can be upwards of 10,000 results to go through and rank. So I added a status bar to show the user how much longer it will take. For the bigger searches, up around 7,000 results, once the status bar reaches about 1/3 of the way across it freezes, but the whole program isn't frozen. Eventually it will return the ranked results to the user. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to run the query without status bar?

Comment: I haven't, though the query still completes, it's just the status bar that freezes. So I don't think this would be much help. I think the problem is that ranking is hogging so much processor power that the UI just has trouble fighting for priority. Any way to let the program breath every 500 records or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's amazing how much stepping away from a project for a while can help. Got in this morning and figured it out within 10 minutes. Every 500 records I pause for an 1/8th and run `DoEvents` this allows the status bar to catch up to the rest of the program.